# jQuery very simple code seems to not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my jQuery code:

```
(function() {


var overlay = {

    init: function() {

    $('<div></div>', {
        class: 'overlay'
    })
        .insertAfter('button');

    }

};

overlay.init();

})();
```

I would expect this to put a div under my button however the HTML that is created contains no div:

```
  <body>

    <button>Reveal More Info</button>

  </body>
```

Sorry if this is a newbie question, I have just started learning.

The HTML Head:

```
<head>
    <title>jQuery rules</title>

    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <style>

    body {
      background: yellow;
    }

    button {
      margin: 100px 0 0 200px;
    }

    div {
      display: none;
      width: 600px;
      height: 400px;
      background-color: white;
      border-radius: 40px;
      position: absolute;
      left: 25%;
      top: 30%;
    }

    </style>

  </head>
```

Comment: The code works fine, http://jsfiddle.net/893gw8ty/ Are you sure you're including the jQuery library correctly?

Comment: Works fine http://jsfiddle.net/ejs1d3zb/

Comment: It depends on when you're calling that closure. It is on the `document.ready` event ? If you're calling it directly on `<head>` section, for instance, it should not work.

Comment: Yes, I do have styling, and jQuery is included properly as other code is working. @DontVoteMeDown what do you mean?

Comment: I mean this: http://jsfiddle.net/ejs1d3zb/1/. I updated @Mikey snippet but I only changed the second dropdown option from `onLoad` to `in <head>`, which means that it will be added - and executed -  **before** the `<body>` being rendered. So the code doens't works because it will try to append to an inexistent `<button>`. Is this clear?

Comment: Check [this tutorial](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Comment: @michaelpri we all supose he inspected the DOM to make sure it wasn't created! haha

Comment: Still a little confused, haha. I have added my head tag in so you can see what it is like. What do I actually need to change?

Comment: In short: Your HTML will be read from top to bottom. If you just put your script in the head of your HTML it will be executed when the browser gets to it. Not loaded elements do not exist for the browser at that moment. To prevent this you wait for the document to be loaded (`window.onload` or `$document.ready` or `$(function(){}`) and then execute the scripts.

Comment: I understand, but wouldn't just putting a $ infront of the opening function do the job? It doesn't seem to help..

Comment: Yes it does the job and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/ejs1d3zb/2/

Comment: It still doesn't work in my files though for some reason... :/

Comment: Or in the Fiddle it seems, when I inspect it

Comment: Please open your console and post the error message

Comment: [Error] TypeError: Object is not a function (near '...})();...')
 global code (script.js, line 26)

Answer (score 2):

From jQuery documentation, see e.g., http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes:

> Blockquote
>   The name "class" must be quoted in the object since it is a JavaScript reserved word, and "className" cannot be used since it refers to the DOM property, not the attribute.

Comment: Thanks but hasn't fixed the problem :/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are including the script.js in your header which is executing before the button is added to the dom so the insertAfter() will not be able to find the `button` to insert the div.

The solution here is to use [document ready handler](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/), or to insert the script at the bottom of the body(just before `</body>`)

```
//dom ready handler
jQuery(function ($) {
    var overlay = {
        init: function () {
            $('<div></div>', {
                'class': 'overlay'
            }).insertAfter('button');
        }
    };
    overlay.init();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/982qagc0/)